# running windows and linux steam games all in one

Tags: wine, games, framerate

Hi I want to be able to play steam games that only run on windows.  The way I have done this by running a windows version of steam with playonlinux.  now the problem is my laptop... it's pretty crap so to increase fps I have downloaded a steam login from here http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-login-to-steam-big-picture-mode-in-ubuntu         so then I logged out and relogged into steam bigpicture mode, but then I realised that I need to be able to play the windows games that are in my windows version of steam that are running in playonlinux.   so can I can play the games in my linux version of steam with it booted in steam bigpicture mode?

OS:Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dualboot Windows 7

p.s any help with increasing my fps is greatly appreciated!